# How to write a program to automate integration testing of Eclipse-RCP GUI?

Tags: testing, eclipse-rcp

I am not particularly conversant with modern desktop GUI program development, having grown up in the days of xlib and worked a bit in Visual Basic and MFC in the late 90s before switching to server development full time.  With that said, I have desktop applications developed in Eclipse RCP (with full access to source) and I would like to build some integration tests.  Ideally I would like to be able to write the following sort of code in Java (or some other language if absolutely necessary):
  1. Enter a specific piece of text into text box "foo".
  2. Execute mouse click on button "bar".
  3. Read the text value displayed in text box "baz" and compare it to the expected value.

In particular, I would prefer to avoid a style of testing where a user is required to record a set of actions on a running program and can then play them back.  Is this at all possible and, if so, how would I do it?  Free/Open Source software for this is preferred, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at

1. [TFTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) an eclipse project for testing and profiling.
2. [SWTBot](http://swtbot.com/) "an open source cross platform UI testing tool for SWT, Eclipse plug-ins and Eclipse RCP based application". [here](http://www.eclipsecon.org/2009/sessions?id=288) for SWTBot + TFTP.  SWTBot works also well with JUnit.

Answer (score 1):

Hey.
You could also write unitTest-like tests that click around application and check for given conditions (assert given properties). You could use:

- [FEST](http://fest.easytesting.org/)
- [Abbot](http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml)